# Possible to have html button in UIWebView content load new ViewController?

Tags: c#, ios, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, uiwebviewdelegate

I am developing a mono touch app and need to have a `UIWebView` take up the entire screen (no navigation controller showing), but have a button on the WebView content be able to load a new ViewController to do barcode scanning.  I am not quite sure how to pull this off with the button being in the actual HTML content and not on the native side.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this even possible?

Should be since it sounds similar to: [response UIWebView click action to call up native code page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8425604/220643)

Except that you'll be using MonoTouch / C# instead of Objective-C. You can convert the code easily using `UIWebViewDelegate` or (better) use the, more .NET-ish, [UIWebView.ShouldStartLoad](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=P:MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWebView.ShouldStartLoad).

There's an example of the later in the answer to: [ShouldStartLoad of custom UIWebViewDelegate not being called when UIWebView request starts loading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5404152/220643)